# What triggers tomcat auto deployment

Tags: linux, tomcat, servlets, jakarta-ee

I have web app defined as follows:

```
<Context path="/myApp" reloadable="true" docBase="/myapps/myApp1">
```

From [Tomcat doc](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/deployer-howto.html) only changes to web.xml or Context xml should trigger redeployment However I found out that even when I change a simple text file under WEB-INF/classes app still gets redeployed:

```
touch /myapps/myApp1/WEB-INF/classes/app.properties
```

So how exactly does Tomcat auto-deployment feature works?

Comment: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html#Automatic_Application_Deployment

Comment: redeploy != reload

Answer (score 2):

When you put the "reloadable" attribute to "true" then it also monitors classes in "/WEB-INF/classes/" and reload the web application if a change is detected.

you may refer the documentation [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html#Attributes) and search for attribute "reloadable".

What you are searching is the attribute [autoDeploy](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/deployer-howto.html#Deploying_on_a_running_Tomcat_server) in the documentation.

I hope this is helpful for you and please let me know if you have any doubt.

Thanks,
Nishant